# Can't connect to docker daemon using powershell

Tags: docker, powershell

When i run the following using windows powershell

```
docker version
```

I get the following error: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

However, when i use Windows command prompt, it works successfully. I'm guessing the path must be configured incorrectly somehow but can't figure out where?

Comment: You can execute `Get-Command docker` in PowerShell to see where it comes from.

Comment: Thank you, turns out I'd created a function to invoke my instance of docker on wsl and totally forgotten about it!